# PowerShell foreach loop with Datagrid rows

Tags: powershell

I am working on a GUI in powershell. I need help writing a `foreach` loop that looks at the information in a DataGrid and creates 2 variables based on the input in the 2 columns of each row.

something like

```
for each row
  v1 = column1
  v2 = column2

  do something

then repeat.
```

Actual code

```
Function RenameComputers{
foreach ($item in $DataGrid.Items){
        $OName = $item.OldName
        $NName = $item.NewName

        write-host "$OName and $NName"
        netdom renamecomputer $OName /newName:$NName /uD:$Username /passwordD:$Password /force /reboot
    }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a great plan, your pseudo code makes sense - what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($item in $dataGrid.Items) {
    $oldname = $item.oldname
    $newname = $item.newname

    //Do stuff, you don't even need to create those variables you can just call $item.attribute
}
```

Then you can call the "columns" with `$item.oldname` or `$item.newname` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't tried much. This is really just a learning experience for so i am looking for examples and how to interact with different objects. I have some experience with Java. So i understand the basics of programming/scripting and its logic.  This is capturing the information the way i need it to, but doesn't appear to be running the command i need it to. I am going to  copy the full function into the original post. I can't seem to get the comments to format correctly. If you have any ideas or suggestions that would be great! Thanks again. You have already been a big help.

Comment: I don't think write-host will ever work. It would be easier to append an existing file or create a text box and write to the text box. I believe it is because the console is in a different run space?

Comment: the write host command is just there for testing purposes. i used it to see if the function was grabbing the names from the data table correctly.  The netdom command is what is not working. I have tried using Invoke-Expression as well with no luck. After the Write-Host command there is no further output or errors reported by the console and the machine never renames.